# fatal: local windows git server repository path does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: git, github, git-config

I have two winodws machines one as git server and other as git client. My server git repository physical path is C:\Users\abcuser\example.git. Server machine ip address is 10.208.27.42 and user is abcuser.

So, I set my remote origin server repository path on client machine as below:
git remote add origin abcuser@10.208.27.42:/Users/abcuser/example.git

I checked if remote origin path is set perfectly with commnd 
git remote -v

origin  abcuser@10.208.27.42:Users/abcuser/example.git (fetch)

origin  abcuser@10.208.27.42:Users/abcuser/example.git (push)

For testing purpose I created a README.txt file in the path C:\Users\abcuser\example.git. Then I committed to local git repository after adding it to staging first. But, I tried to push it to remote repository using the below command
git origin push master

But, It always giving me below error becuse of which I couldn't push it successfully to remote server.

$  git push origin master

abcuser@10.208.27.42's password:

fatal: ''Users/abcuser/example.git'' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the remote branch exists by `git branch -a`.

> remotes/origin/master

Should be present in the list, else it'll be the case of error.
To make sure you are inside a git repository, `start .` should open up the folder in explorer and it should have a hidden folder

> ".git"

Comment: Hi, the command outputs me as below Command: $ git branch -a,
Output: * master

Comment: The second command also working properly. Opens a file explorer with .git folder inside it. Can you please check my command used to add remote repository path :)

Comment: Ping the server IP and make sure it is reachable. This[link](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) might be helpful in setting up the server. As you have conformed the above two checks, then issue has to be with either user credentials or remote server setup.